# XSLT use value-of inside select (Nested value-of select)

Tags: xslt

I am trying to pass the result of a value-of select to a parameter of another value-of select. 
Here is the full code with pseudo statement (myVar)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="data" select="document('user.xml')/user/data" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="form/field">
            <p class="field">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">left:<xsl:value-of
                select="left" />;top:<xsl:value-of select="top" />;
                </xsl:attribute>
                myVar = <xsl:value-of select="text" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$data[@key = {@myVar}]/@value" />
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So what is the question? There seems to be none. What is the source XML document? What is the wanted result? What are the requirements that the transformation must implement? Please, edit the question and provide all of this missing and important information.

Comment: This is clearly nonsense: `select="$data[@key = {@myVar}]/@value"`. But please, don't expect to enter nonsense in your question and ask people to correct it. How are we to guess what it was supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to pass the result of a value-of select to a parameter of
>   another value-of select.
>
> ```
>         myVar = <xsl:value-of select="text" />
>         <xsl:value-of select="$data[@key = {@myVar}]/@value" />
> ```

The above line is syntactically incorrect -- `select` is the only attribute that doesn't accept AVT.

**In order to achieve the wanted result replace the above with:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="$data[@key = current()/text]/@value" />
```

**Explanation**: Proper use of the XSLT **[`current()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current)** function.